# show product name in opencart order history

Tags: javascript, php, opencart

On my website its quite important to show products names on Order history (my_account/order_history), while in opencart there is only shown order id. I have partly solved the problem however I would very appreciate some hints how to proceed.
The topic was once opened in 2011 in http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=46387&p=437991#p437991

1. The main problem is that the file order_list.tpl doesnt have access to `$product['name']` in controller order.php (where its defined in `function info()` instead of `function index()`), only order_info.tpl have.  I tried to copy the parts of the code from the function info() to the function index() but it still didnt have access there. Any hint what I have to do ? Do i need to change something in model file ? or how to modify controller file (order.php) to allow order_list.tpl to have the right access ?
2. One approach I have tried is rendering the content order_info using javascript on the order_list.tpl in new div (as described in http://goo.gl/nMXhEu ) however as a newbie in js I coudlnt modify it to open right after page-load (not on moveover). I have tried to change mouseover to load, beforeload a few other without any success..

---

```
$("body").on("mouseover", function(e){
    $(".order-info").load(e.target.href, function(){
        $(e.target).addClass("unloaded");
    });
});
```

Any help or hint how to proceed would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for help cske, I really appreciate it. However I still could not make it work. I also tried to make some small adjustments, without any success (but then I am not js developer).

So I decided to try once again to modify the controller file, to make `$product['name']` accessible to  `order_list.tpl` (as described in the question). I was able to do so by adding

```
 $products = $this->model_account_order->getOrderProducts($result['order_id']);
```

and

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
$this->data['products'][] = array('name'=> $product['name'],);
}
```

after

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
```

which makes possible to call it in orders array for example

```
$this->data['orders'][] = array(
'product_name'       => $product['name'],
```

It is working solution however:
 1. it shows only one product per order 
 2. it throws notice

```
Notice: Undefined index: order_id
```

The notice can be turned off in Admin area.

I am Ok with this solution, but obviously it might not be the right solution for other shops.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
  $(".order-info a").each(function () {
    var $me  = $(this);     
    $me.load($me.attr('href'),function(){ 
            $me.addClass("unloaded");
    };      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the solution that only shows the first product for the order to figure out how to show all products for the order and their quantities.

Instead of:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $this->data['products'][] = array('name'=> $product['name'],);
}
```

use:

```
$this->data['products'] = array();
$prod = "";

foreach ($products as $product) {
    $prod .= $product['quantity'] . " x " . $product['name'] .'<br>';
}
```

and in:

```
$this->data['orders'][] = array(
```

add:

```
'product_data' => $prod,
```

then in order_list.tpl you can get the product list with quantities with:

```
<?php echo $order['product_data']; ?>
```